# Encoding of HTML not declared

Tags: mysql, forms

I'm just in the process of stepping through a mySQL course and i've come unstuck. My intention is to create a basic login form. I have created the form alone and it appears however as soon as i add the 'else' command in the below code i get the following error:

> The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

What am i missing?

```
<?php

if ($_POST['submit']) {
  if (!$_POST['email']) {
    $error.='Please enter your email';
  }
  else { 
    !(filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) $error.='Please enter a valid email';
  }


?>

<form>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
  <input type="password" name="password"/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign up" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a closing bracket for your else statement.  It should come after the line that begins !(filter_var...

```
<?php
  if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if (!$_POST['email']) {
      $error.='Please enter your email';
    } 
    else { 
      !(filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) $error.='Please enter a valid email';
    }
  }

  ?>

  <form>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
    <input type="password" name="password"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign up" />
  </form>
```

That line, BTW, looks invalid as well.  I think it should be

```
 elseif(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
   $error.='Please enter a valid email';
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Robert. I corrected both and this part now works. I can continue with the code from the course